# Как добавить в jupyter notebook выбор другой версии Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

Jypyter Notebook работает по умолчанию с anaconda_3 и Python_3.6. Сейчас начинаю задание, где крайне рекомендовано всё делать во втором Питоне.
    Как добавить возможность выбора из двух Питонов? Будут ли работать со вторым Питоном все имеющиеся пакеты (scikit-learn первую очередь) и зависимости? 
OS Ubuntu_16

Comment: Jypyter Notebook - локальный? Используете VirtualEnv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начиная с Anaconda 4.1.0 можно сделать так:

```
conda create -n py27 python=2.7 ipykernel
conda create -n py36 python=3.6 ipykernel
```

для более старых версий можно [зарегистрировать "kernels" вручную](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30492913/5741205):

Python 2.7:

```
conda create -n py27 python=2.7
source activate py27
conda install notebook ipykernel
ipython kernel install --user
```

Python 3.6:

```
conda create -n py36 python=3.6
source activate py36
conda install notebook ipykernel
ipython kernel install --user
```

После этого в Jupyter Notebook должна появится возможность выбрать `Python 2` или `Python 3`

PS подробнее об этом можно почитать [в этом замечательном ответе из англоязычной версии SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30492913/5741205)

Comment: Там на локальном форуме нашёл совет - понизить версию пакета, это лучше и проще чем для одной задачи менять весь дистрибутив Питона. Я там и сделал, ответ зашёл. Вам большое спасибо за полный полезный ответ, сохраню.